# No need to delete dynamic data?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f {
        cout << "2" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new B();
    a->f();
    return 0;
}
```

And my question is: why there is no need to to delete a before return of the main function?
According to my understanding this code will result in a memory leak, am I wrong?

[UPDATE]
I checked the following code using valgrind and it confused me even more. It says there is a memory leak.

Comment: The type will at least store the address of it's member functions, so I'd say that whoever told you this was wrong.

Comment: It's not as much a *leak* as it is just something you haven't cleaned up. It's a proper leak once you actually forget the reference, e.g. if you had said `a = nullptr;`. Leaks are always bad, whereas leaving something unreclaimed at the end like that is sometimes done.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a memory leak. It lasts from the return of `main` to the exit of the program, which in this case is very, very short.

Answer (score 0):

> *"According to my understanding this code will result in a memory leak, am I wrong?"*

No you're right, there should be a `delete`. Though the memory leak usually doesn't matter, since the OS will reclaim all memory allocated from the process after `return 0;`.